# Setting <td> width throwing off table display?

Tags: html, html-table, styles, width

I'm totally stuck trying to figure out why setting a td width attribute in the following table is throwing off the display.

```html
 <table style="width:100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <big><big><b>Investments By Bruce Wayne</b></big></big>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Date</u></b></td>
                <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Invested</u></b></td>
                <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>Company (and Round)</u></b></td>
                <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>SPV</u></b></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The above is rendered with the word "Invested" outside of the table entirely ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7qiv.png)).

Any thoughts on why this might be happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [two identical html tables display differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63344138/two-identical-html-tables-display-differently)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <big><big><b>Investments By Bruce Wayne</b></big></big>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Date</u></b></td>
                <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Invested</u></b></td>
                <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>SPV</u></b></td>
                <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>Company (and Round)</u></b></td>
                
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**
All you have to do is to format your code. There is a `NON-BREAKING-SPACE` between td and style `<td style` (the one with the `Investment` text) that destroys the layout. To reproduce you can delete the whitespace and add the whitespace again.

**Note:**
You have to `<big><big>` there wrapped - this can be reduced to just one element.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <big><b>Investments By Bruce Wayne</b></big>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Date</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Invested</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>Company (and Round)</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>SPV</u></b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```