# two identical html tables display differently

Tags: html, html-table

why do these tables display differently?

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Date</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Invested</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>Company (and Round)</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>SPV</u></b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br><br><br>


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Date</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Invested</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>Company (and Round)</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>SPV</u></b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not here https://onlinegdb.com/B1V6LlkGP

Comment: Might be some strange character or space we can't see at first glance, because if I copy the second table over the first, the problem goes away. The second table seems fine, the first table alone has the issue

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please see the screenshot. The problem is in the gap.

Comment: Astounding how similar this question is to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343424/setting-td-width-throwing-off-table-display. You answered it too?

Comment: I saw that post and was really stumped.  I probably should just have redirected them to this post.  I'll correct that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I surmised in my comment above, the space in `<td style="width:20%;">` is a non-breaking space (`U+00A0 : NO-BREAK SPACE [NBSP]`) which can render as `<tdstyle="width:20%;">`. Just delete the sapce between `td` and `style` and enter a proper space and you're fine. Character identified via https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html

Answer (score 1):

The difference is here, in the [screenshot](https://ibb.co/j827BfM). In the DOM structure, in this line there is a space, like `$nbsp`. Perhaps you copied this line from another editor. Use it:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Date</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Invested</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>Company (and Round)</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>SPV</u></b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br><br><br>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Date</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:20%;"><b><u>Invested</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>Company (and Round)</u></b></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><b><u>SPV</u></b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```